# How to make Laravel & Lumen projects running simultaneously using Docker at the same time?

Tags: docker

I wonder is it possible to run both Laravel + Lumen at the same time using Docker? So I created a fresh installation of Laravel and Lumen in separate folder, so I'm going to use Lumen for the API, and I want to know if it's possible to run both of them using only one container.

I already tried with changing the ports but still no luck, the Laravel running smoothly but not for the Lumen.

Here are the files, they are identical, but the differences are only the ports ( I don't know if what I'm doing is right or not)

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: web.dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    links:
      - app

  app:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: app.dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    links:
      - database
    environment:
      - "DB_PORT=3306"
      - "DB_HOST=database"

  database:
    image: mysql:5.6
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
        MYSQL_DATABASE: dockerApp
    ports:
        - "33061:3306"

  cache:
    image: redis:3.0
    ports: 
      - "63791:6379"
```

`app.dockerfile`

```
FROM php:7.1.19-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev mysql-client \
    && docker-php-ext-install mcrypt pdo_mysql

WORKDIR /var/www
```

`web.dockerfile`

```
FROM nginx:1.10

ADD ./vhost.conf/ /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

WORKDIR /var/www
```

`vhost.conf`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    root /var/www/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;

        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

```
docker ps

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                           COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                      NAMES
33987802df30        test-restful-api_web            "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   34 hours ago        Up About a minute   80/tcp, 443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32768->8001/tcp   test-restful-api_web_1
7f4b767ff2af        test-restful-api_app            "docker-php-entrypoi…"   34 hours ago        Up About a minute   9000/tcp                                   test-restful-api_app_1
be0675a6804d        redis:3.0                       "docker-entrypoint.s…"   34 hours ago        Up About a minute   6379/tcp, 0.0.0.0:63793->63792/tcp         test-restful-api_cache_1
f0b5fe2db9a4        mysql:5.6                       "docker-entrypoint.s…"   34 hours ago        Up About a minute   3306/tcp, 0.0.0.0:33063->33062/tcp         test-restful-api_database_1
bdb308c7288f        test_web                        "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   34 hours ago        Up About a minute   443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp              test_web_1
a74a1b5c2ec7        test_app                        "docker-php-entrypoi…"   34 hours ago        Up About a minute   9000/tcp                                   test_app_1
690b553eae36        mysql:5.6                       "docker-entrypoint.s…"   34 hours ago        Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:33061->3306/tcp                    test_database_1
fc47a3a84484        redis:3.0                       "docker-entrypoint.s…"   34 hours ago        Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:63791->6379/tcp                    test_cache_1
```

**What I'm trying to achieve**

I want to make something like this in the hosting `test.com` **(the main website)** and `api.test.com` **(for restful api)**, but instead in my machine, I want to run it something like this (if possible)
localhost:8080 (the website)
localhost:8000/8001 (restful api)

**UPDATE**

I just make a changes for the directory, before it was like this

```
all_project_folder
---- test // front end project folder which is using Laravel 5.8
-------- * bunch of laravel things
-------- web.dockerfile
-------- app.dockerfile
-------- vhost.conf
-------- docker-compose.yml
---- test-restful-api // restful api project folder which is using Lumen 5.8
-------- * bunch of laravel things
-------- web.dockerfile
-------- app.dockerfile
-------- vhost.conf
-------- docker-compose.yml
```

But now I already changes it to this structure

```
all_project_folder
---- test // folder for grouping the api and frontend
-------- frontend // test frontend folder which is laravel
-------- * bunch of laravel things
------------ web.dockerfile
------------ app.dockerfile
------------ vhost.conf
-------- restful-api // test api folder which is lumen
------------ web.dockerfile
------------ app.dockerfile
------------ vhost.conf
-------- docker-compose.yml // now there's only 1 docker-compose file, and it's outside those 2 folders (and the project can be added something like backend)
```

So now how to setting the dockerfile using the `version 3`? I already tried read the documentation but I still didn't get it, and there are multiple examples that different with each other, so I'm not sure which one I should use. (sorry i'm very new with this server things)

[image]

**docker-compose.yml** my latest approach by returns an error `ERROR: Service "web" uses an undefined network "frontend"`

```
version: '3'

services:  
  web:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: frontend/web.dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    networks:
      - frontend
      - api

  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: frontend/app.dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    networks:
      - database
    environment:
      - "DB_PORT=3306"
      - "DB_HOST=database"

  api:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: restful-api/app.dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    networks:
      - database
    environment:
      - "DB_PORT=3306"
      - "DB_HOST=database"

  database:
    image: mysql:5.6
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
        MYSQL_DATABASE: dockerApp
    ports:
        - "33061:3306"

  cache:
    image: redis:3.0
    ports: 
      - "63791:6379"
```

I just added `networks to my docker-compose.yml` but get this error instead

> ERROR: The Compose file '.\docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
>   Unsupported config option for services.networks: 'frontend'

```
networks:
    frontend: 
      driver: asisten-pajak-frontend
    api:
      driver: asisten-pajak-api
```

Comment: Can you add some details of your setup to the question, and any error messages you’re getting?  Running unrelated projects on the same Docker instance is pretty routine.

Comment: I'd recommend that you decouple both applications into separate containers though

Comment: @DavidMaze I already put my setup, and there are no errors at all, it just doesn't running even though when i'm doing the `docker ps` all the containers are there

Comment: @cousine I think I already separate the containers with changing the ports, is it not enough?

Comment: I'd recommend four containers - your API (Lumen), your web app (Laravel), your database, and a frontend proxy (e.g. Traefik). This will help you route your API and your web traffic via the same standard ports (80 and/or 443).

Comment: I edited the question. I assumed by "running in one Docker" you mean one container, and yet you are using multiple containers in Docker Compose. What did you mean by this?

Comment: @halfer sorry I don't have any idea about server before this, and I just learned about this docker from youtube and want to try it so it'll be easier for me to make a projects.

Comment: @halfer so how to make it as 4 containers with my settings which you recommend? do you have any examples? it'll help me the most

Comment: @halfer Hi, please check my updated question, I just put my approach for `docker-compose.yml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the answer after several days trying to understand docker, and at the end, the answer I got is using [Laradock](https://laradock.io/), and you can follow this [Laradock documentation](https://laradock.io/getting-started/#B) for multiple projects/container.